# How to join together these tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, rdbms

I have the following situation:

I have this query that JOIN together two differents table respectivelly named **VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId** and **CPE** passing passing through the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe** that bound the two tables in a many to many relation:

```
SELECT CPE.* FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe VAD_CPE
            INNER JOIN Cpe CPE ON VAD_CPE.CpeId = CPE.Id
            WHERE VAD_CPE.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = 87926
```

This query work well and I obtain the following output:

```
Id         Cpe                          SourceId    vendor_id    product_id
27975      cpe:/o:google:android:1.0    NVD         984          3967
27976      cpe:/o:google:android:1.1    NVD         984          3967
27977      cpe:/o:otherCPE              NVD         111          2222
```

So, as you can see, in this output I have two fields named **vendor_id** and **product_id** that directly bound a single record to two tables named **CpeVendor** and  **CpeProduct** that both have the following columns: **id**, **nome** and **date_added**

So, now my problem is that I want obtain the **nome** column value in the previous query output.

I think that, for each output record of the previous query, I also have to join with the **CpeVendor** and **CpeProduct** tables but I am not sure about it. Can you help me to solve this problem?

Tnx

Answer (score 3):

Try adding the two tables to your query:

```
SELECT CPE.*, p.nome as Product, c.nome as Vendor 
FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocument_Cpe VAD_CPE
  INNER JOIN Cpe CPE ON VAD_CPE.CpeId = CPE.Id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CpeVendor c  ON CPE.vendor_id = c.vendor_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CpeProduct p on CPE.product_id = p.product_id
WHERE VAD_CPE.VulnerabilityAlertDocumentId = 87926
```